# Build failed while builing in release mode

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am trying to generate signed build but it shows the below error:

```
Warning:there were 87 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Exception while processing task 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:app:dexRelease
:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease
:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of D:\Project\AppLocker\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.629 secs
Information:1 error
Information:62 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I tried rebuild/clean build option but still I am getting the same error everytime.

My project has following dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.2.+'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Please suggest how to fix the above issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ProGuard may be stripping out the classes that your build relies on. Try doing a release build with ProGuard disabled (minifyEnabled false) and see if that works. If this works then you need to configure your ProGuard rules to not strip out the types your code relies on.

Comment: Without proguard, it is working fine. But facing issue while using proguard.

Comment: What dependencies do you have?

Comment: Take a look here for an example of getting ProGuard rules configured for Android apps: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/examples (the repo also contains a lot of rules for typical Android dependencies)

Comment: Updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding `-ignorewarnings` at the top of my proguard rule file.

Comment: if you do this, dont use proguard, it is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding packagingOptions to the gradle, try cleaning the project,delete the build folder and rebuild again,Specify all the jar files u have used in gradle.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Try creating fresh copy of your project. I was facing the same issue and I had to create a new copy of the project. increase the version number in the gradle file